# How can I implement proportional editing with Geometry Nodes for vertices?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create multiple variations of a base mesh by scaling some of its parts using *Geometry Nodes*.

I tried to scale the vertices, but I wanted the neighboring vertices to scale according to the specified radius of influence.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it can be done. However, an answer would be a bit more specific, so it would be good if you could share your current node tree, and/or your blend file. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same question. For example, making a hourglass out of a cylinder.

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 3):

> Since you have unfortunately not gone into more detail about your request, I can unfortunately only make assumptions here and illustrate a possible solution with an example.

I assume that you want to move a certain point whose index you select manually.

All surrounding points should also be moved in a certain radius or range in this direction, so that the result is similar to *Proportional Editing*.

You can solve this for example as follows:

[image]

Here I first separate the point I want to move.

Then I use `Geometry Proximity` and define the range that should be affected as well.

The vector shown here is the target position to which I move the selected point as well as the surrounding points in the defined area with `Set Position`.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>